# Java HTTP Server and Resources

Tags: java, android, http, nanohttpd

I'm using NanoHTTPd to serve files from my android app. I can open the .html files fine but it's trying to view images that's the problem. Anything like a webpages background image doesn't display.

Does anybody have any example code for this. I know nanoHTTPd can do this. I've lots of experience with Android and Java but this is the first time I've use a server.

```
private class MyHTTPD extends NanoHTTPD {
    public MyHTTPD() throws IOException {
        super(PORT, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(String uri, String method, Properties header, Properties parms, Properties files) {
        Log.d("response", "URI:" + uri + " method: " + method + " header: " + header + " parms: " + parms + " files: " + files);
        final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for (Entry<Object, Object> kv : header.entrySet())
            buf.append(kv.getKey() + " : " + kv.getValue() + "\n");
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                hello.setText(buf);
            }
        });

        String html = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        if (uri.length() > 3) {
            // respond with resource or sub page

            // serve image?
            if (uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("."), uri.length()).equals(".jpg")) {
                try {
                    is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile" + uri);
                    Log.d("Serve", "image: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile" + uri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                //serve page
                try {
                    is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile" + uri);
                    Log.d("response subpage", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile" + uri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            // respond with index
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile/" + "index.html");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("response index", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile/" + "index.html");
        }

        byte[] b;
        try {
            b = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(b);
            html = new String(b);
        } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new NanoHTTPD.Response(HTTP_OK, MIME_HTML, html);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

opening an image in the browser just returns lots of text symbols(...ï¿½ï¿½kï¿½OOOï¿½...). Am I parsing the image the wrong way?

Fix:

Like Gustav said I wasn't using the corrent meme types but also I wasn't returning serveFile(.....) e.g.....

```
// serve image?
            if (uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("."), uri.length()).equals(".jpeg")) {
                try {
                    is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile" + uri);
                    mimeType = "image/jpeg";
                    Log.d("Serve", "image: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile" + uri);
                    return serveFile(uri, header, new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile"), true);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
            } else {
                //serve page
                try {
                    is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile" + uri);
                    mimeType = MIME_HTML;
                    Log.d("response subpage", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile" + uri);
                    return serveFile(uri, header, new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile"), true);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
            }
        } else {
            // respond with index
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile/" + "index.html");
                mimeType = MIME_HTML;
                Log.d("response index", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile/" + "index.html");
                return serveFile(uri, header, new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WiFile"), true);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `MIME_HTML` to the `Response` constructor regardless of what you're going to send as payload. The parameter is a `String`, so try

```
return new NanoHTTPD.Response(HTTP_OK, "image/jpeg", html);
```

when serving (JPEG) images.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've made amendments so that when I'm sending the jped images it uses "image/jpeg" as the mime type. Only now I get a corrupt image icon. Any ideas?